# How can I make my iPhone output an input?

Tags: audio, headphones

I’m looking for an anwser to the following situation.

I have audio coming in from an external source (with an audio jack) and I want to record it on my iPhone.

Who has the magic solution?

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you tried the Voice recorder app built into the macOS?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried that app but it won’t record the audio. The music still plays but goes silent once the voice recorder or screenrecoder start.

Comment: “*The music still plays?*” can you please describe exactly what you’re trying to do?

Comment: I’m trying to record the audio from my headphone onto my phone. For exemple I’m listening to music on YouTube or any other app and I want to record that audio on my phone. Without using Bluetooth, cause my headphones uses an audiojack

Comment: Usually headphones don’t provide an audio signal on the wire. What model do you use?

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that you use Bluetooth to send audio from the iPhone to your headphones and now want to use the audio jack to capture the audio with the same phone?

Comment: I use my headphones with a wire. So not via Bluetooth and I can’t use Bluetooth. It’s a quite simple model.

Comment: Let me rephrase it. 
I have a source where I plug my headphones into. Now I want to hear the music through my headphones and record it at the same time. So probably need an audiosplitter, im already that far.

Comment: So your headphones are kind of irrelevant here, you have an external source and want to connect it to your iPhone to record the audio on it (of course you need a splitter to connect your headphones to the same source, but that's kind of not relevant for the question). Can you please edit your question to make this more easy to understand?

Comment: Also, there is a lot of material already out there on this (see https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+audio+recording+from+external+source for a start). What have you tried so far, how does it fail?

Comment: I connected my source to my iPhone and tried recording it through screenrecord and voice memo app, but it doesn’t pic up the sound. Guess it doesn’t recognises it as input.

Comment: iPhones don't have a stereo line in, they only have a mono mic input, so even if you impedance & level match your source to destination, you will still only get mono. You will need a dedicated audio interface to record stereo. Such as https://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/?S1=491&S2=497

Comment: Damn, I was hoping for a simple costless solution. :D

Comment: Do you think something like this will work? https://www.amazon.com/Cubilux-Lightning-Microphone-Monitoring-Compatible/dp/B08Q38FVQP 

Where I plug the source into the hole of the mic using an aux cable.

Comment: Not from a regular TRRS headset plug. It's designed for a headset with separate headphone/mic plugs [old style desktop stuff] & still would not be impendance or level-matched, even if you squeezed another plug adaptor in between. You're trying to do something the iPhone was simply never designed to do. Many modern laptops are the same these days, no line in at all, only headset mic.

Comment: Damn… that’s not the anwser I was hoping for. Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: One last question, do you know if this really works? 
The iPhone won’t record through its headphone jack (or headphone jack dongle) unless it thinks it’s connected to a headset. That means you need a special cable. If you ever bought some headphones that have a detachable cable with an inline remote and mic, then you’re in luck.

Comment: Came from this website: https://www.cultofmac.com/610284/how-to-record-any-audio-on-your-iphone/amp/

Comment: That was written by someone who knows iPhones but doesn't really know anything about audio. The cable may 'work' for a given definition of 'work'. It will still be impedance & level mis-matched & be in mono.